# Output changes when I put my code into a function

Tags: c++, output

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        char str[100], str1[100];
        cin>>str>>str1;
        char c[strlen(str1)], flag[strlen(str1)];
        int i, j, k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++) {
            flag[i] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(str1); j++) {
                if (str[i] == str1[j] && flag[j] == 0) {
                    c[k] = str[i];
                    k++;
                    flag[j] = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (k != 0)
            cout<<c;
        return 0;
}
```

It gives the correct output(first line is the input):

```
hello world
lo
```

But it requires to be put inside a function `func()` when I put the code in a function, such as this -

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char * func(char * str, char * str1){
    char c[strlen(str1)], flag[strlen(str1)];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++) {
        flag[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(str1); j++) {
            if (str[i] == str1[j] && flag[j] == 0) {
                c[k] = str[i];
                k++;
                flag[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (k != 0)
        return c;
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
        char str[100], str1[100];
        cin>>str>>str1;
        cout<<func(str,str1);
        return 0;
}
```

The output comes like

```
hello world
```

Note that the second output line contains an ASCII character
What is the mistake in here? Can't I return a string array like this?

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: This is not a judge based question! I just told that for extra info so as to why I want to use a function. The main question is to why the output changes

Comment: Debug?? ........

Comment: I've tried debugging it. I still don't know why the output changes

Comment: std::string is much more sensible, and takes care of error prone details for you in a well documented and tested library

Comment: that is true, but the judge I'm submitting to required a character array as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing, in `func()`,

```
char c[strlen(str1)], flag[strlen(str1)];
```

in

```
static char c[100];
char flag[strlen(str1)];
```

otherwise, when you

```
return c;
```

you're returning a local variable that go out of scope; when you

```
cout<<func(str,str1);
```

the behaviour is undefined.

If you transform `c` is a `static` variable, the `char *` returned by `func()` is still alive outside `func()` and can be used without problems.

Comment: It's more common for the caller to pass in the output buffer (and its length), for this approach.

Comment: @KennyOstrom - You're right; but I think, in this case, that is more important, for the OP, understand that he can't return the address of a temporary variable and expect that can be used outside the scope

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a local variable 'c' from the function. It will get destroyed as soon as processor gets back from the function. either print the value in the function or pass a destination string and copy it.

I suggest using 'string' class instead char.

here you go

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
string func(char * str, char * str1){
     char c[strlen(str1)], flag[strlen(str1)];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++) {
        flag[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(str1); j++) {
            if (str[i] == str1[j] && flag[j] == 0) {
                c[k] = str[i];
                k++;
                flag[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    string s = c;
    if (k != 0)
        return s;
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
        char str[100], str1[100];
        cin>>str>>str1;
        cout<<func(str,str1);
        return 0;
}
```

you can resolve by declaring 'c' as static also. But the length of 'c'  should be hard coded.